# Docusign signature behavior on composite templates

Tags: docusignapi

we are making composite templates in docusign, which had been working just fine until 2 days ago.  All of the sudden, we see this red dotted line near the signature area on the last signature, and it is not clickable or signable.

anyone had similar experience?  or any insight into the red outline?  usually the outline appears black..

[see here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J46sr.png)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem or error you are running into?  The red outline shows when you try to hit the `FINISH` button and you have not signed all the required signature fields.  It's a platform wide update so all accounts show this as the default behavior now, I think it helps highlight which tabs the recipient has missed.